# How do I build a solution programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, msbuild, build, project, solution

How do I build a C# solution programmatically?

I should be able to pass the path of a solution and get the output messages (or just build the solution). How do I achieve this in C#?

I need this because we are building a single solution for our projects when it now gets everything from SVN and also builds it. Next would be deploying it all in one click.

Comment: @Nix: I think the OP means "compile code at runtime"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically build a visual studio solution ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713075/how-to-programmatically-build-a-visual-studio-solution)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most of the answers are providing ways to do it by calling external commands, but there *is* an API, [Microsoft.Build.Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.aspx), to build via C#.

---

Code from blog post:

```
using Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

public class SolutionBuilder
{
    BasicFileLogger b;
    public SolutionBuilder() { }

    [STAThread]
    public string Compile(string solution_name,string logfile)
    {
        b = new BasicFileLogger();
        b.Parameters = logfile;
        b.register();
        Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.GlobalEngine.BuildEnabled = true;
        Project p = new Project (Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.GlobalEngine);
        p.BuildEnabled = true;
        p.Load(solution_name);
        p.Build();
        string output = b.getLogoutput();
        output += “nt” + b.Warningcount + ” Warnings. “;
        output += “nt” + b.Errorcount + ” Errors. “;
        b.Shutdown();
        return output;
    }
}
// The above class is used and compilation is initiated by the following code,
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SolutionBuilder builder = new SolutionBuilder();
    string output = builder.Compile(@”G:CodesTestingTesting2web1.sln”, @”G:CodesTestingTesting2build_log.txt”);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note the code in that blog post works, but it is a little dated. The

`Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine`

has been broken up into some pieces.

`Microsoft.Build.Construction`

`Microsoft.Build.Evaluation`

`Microsoft.Build.Execution`

Comment: looks like "Automated compilation of Visual Studio Projects through C# using MSBuild" link is broken

Comment: This info is outdated - if you use the Engine class, you'll get this warning: "This class has been deprecated. Please use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection from the Microsoft.Build assembly instead.".  So the answer below using Project and ProjectCollection is the right answer.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page, *".NET API Browser"*.

Comment: What blog post is referred to? What is its link? (Respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6511466/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate).)

Answer (score 30):

See *[.NET 4.0 MSBuild API introduction](http://www.odewit.net/ArticleContent.aspx?id=MsBuildApi4&format=html)* for an example using the .NET 4.0 MSBuild API:

```
List<ILogger> loggers = new List<ILogger>();
loggers.Add(new ConsoleLogger());
var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
projectCollection.RegisterLoggers(loggers);
var project = projectCollection.LoadProject(buildFileUri); // Needs a reference to System.Xml
try
{
    project.Build();
}
finally
{
    projectCollection.UnregisterAllLoggers();
}
```

A simpler example:

```
var project = new Project(buildFileUri, null, "4.0");
var ok = project.Build(); // Or project.Build(targets, loggers)
return ok;
```

Remember to use the *.NET 4 Profile* (not the *Client profile*).

Add the following references: System.XML, Microsoft.Build, Microsoft.Build.Framework, and optionally Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.

Also look at Stack Overflow question *[Running MSBuild programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264682/running-msbuild-programmatically)*.

To build a solution, do the following:

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
props["Configuration"] = "Release";
var request = new BuildRequestData(buildFileUri, props, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
var parms = new BuildParameters();
// parms.Loggers = ...;

var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(parms, request);
return result.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// Fix to the path of your MSBuild executable
var pathToMsBuild = "C:\\Windows\\DotNet\\Framework\\msbuild.exe";

Process.Start(pathToMsBuild + " " + pathToSolution);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a .proj file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Common -->
    <Solution Include="Common\Util\Util.sln"/>
    <Solution Include="Common\EventScheduler\EventSchedulerSolution\EventSchedulerSolution.sln"/>
    <!-- Server -->
    <Solution Include="Server\DataLayer\DataTransferObjects\SharedModel\SharedModel.sln"/>
    <Solution Include="Server\DataLayer\DataTier\ESPDAL.sln"/>
    <!-- Internal Tools -->
    <Solution Include="InternalTools\ServerSchemaUtility\ServerSchemaUtility.sln"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Solution)" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=Release"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And then call msbuild.exe using the project file as an argument. Below is a batch file example. From C#, you could call Process.Start as indicated by other posters.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" BuildSolutions.proj

pause
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try blog post *[Take control of MSBuild using MSBuild API](http://bogdangavril.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/take-control-of-msbuild-using-msbuild-api/)*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to trigger the build from Visual Studio extension code, you must consider the limitations imposed by IVsBuildManagerAccessor interface - see the
*General Notes*, including new IVsBuildManagerAccessor.docx
from [Managed Package Framework for Projects](https://mpfproj12.codeplex.com/).
Its fork is also available [at GitHub](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/MPFProj10/blob/master/Documentation/General%20Notes%20Including%20new%20IVsBuildManagerAccessor.docx).

> In Visual Studio 2010 with MSBuild 4.0, there are new interactions
> between the Solution Build Manager and MSBuild which impact project
> systems utilizing these services.  MSBuild 4.0 contains a new
> component called the Build Manager (not to be confused with the
> Solution Build Manager which is a VS component) which controls the
> submission of build requests.  This became necessary as Visual Studio
> 2010 now allows parallel builds to occur (notably native projects) and
> access to shared resources such as the CPU needed to be mediated. For
> project systems which previously simply called Project.Build() to
> invoke a build several changes must be made.  The project system now
> must:
>
> 1. Ask for the SVsBuildManagerAccessor service using the IServiceProvider interface.  This should be done soon after the
>    project system is loaded, well before any builds might occur.
> 2. Notify the system if you need the UI thread
> 3. Notify the system if you are doing a design-time build.
> 4. Register its loggers using the Build Manager Accessor.
> 5. Submit build requests directly to the MSBuild Build Manager, rather than invoking a method on the Project.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can use MSBuild to build any Visual Studio solution file.

I believe you can use `Process.Start` to invoke MSBuild with appropriate parameters.