# Build a C# solution programatally

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i build a solution programatically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511380/how-do-i-build-a-solution-programatically-in-c)

It's there a way to build a solution from a with c# code by an API or library??.

Because I only found how to do it by the command line [in this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tharakram/BuildDotNetSolution11162005052301AM/BuildDotNetSolution.aspx)

Comment: May I ask, why do you need this?

Comment: Because I need to create a .DLL in runtime and added to a project template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but here's an article that explains how to compile code programmatically:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Here's some of the relevant code from that article:

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
    string Output = "Out.exe";
    Button ButtonObject = (Button)sender;

    textBox2.Text = "";
    System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
    //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
    parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
    CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text);

    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
                        "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                        ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                        ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Successful Compile
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        textBox2.Text = "Success!";
        //If we clicked run then launch our EXE
        if (ButtonObject.Text == "Run") Process.Start(Output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For quite a while now the way to build .NET solutions and projects is to use [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).

Project and Solution files are MSBuild files.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your applications using MSBuild and passing the project as a parameter :

```
MSBuild.exe MyProj.proj /property:Configuration=Debug
```

You can start this process from C# using `System.Diagnostics.Process`