# How can I get output file names after a C# MSBuild completes?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am using [BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.execution.buildmanager.build.aspx) to build a visual studio solution which contains many projects.  My code looks a [lot like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718438/672).

Once the build completes, I'd like to copy the output (DLLs in my case) to a target folder.

But I don't see any way to retrieve the file names of the build output from the BuildResult.

I can [scan the SLN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802027/how-do-i-programmatically-list-all-projects-in-a-solution#3802263) file and then infer the output locations.  But that will be error-prone and tedious.

Build() returns a [BuildResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.execution.buildresult.aspx).  As far as I can tell, BuildResult does not contain the actual output file names.

How can I get the output file names after a build completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide an output path for the build. Just clear the folder before you build and work with the newly generated files.

```
var solutionPath = "...";
var outputPath = "...";

var pc = new ProjectCollection();
var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
properties.Add("OutputPath", outputPath);

var request = new BuildRequestData(solutionPath, properties, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), request);

// do stuffs with the dlls
var libraries = Directory.GetFiles(outputPath, "*.dll");
```